# What is the scope of the mocks created by mocha when used in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, ruby-mocha

In my rspec test suite I use mocha library to create mocks/stubs and test doubles. Examples in my rspec suite run in random order, as recommended. For some reason a few examples now fail randomly. I already ruled out shared database state and global variables (*I confess: there are global variables in my Rails app*).

Another logical suspect (maybe) is the mocking library. According to rspec documentation [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/scope) rspec would clean out all mocks after each example, even those created in before(:all). This should work with any mocking library, right? Maybe...

For historic reasons my test suite doesn't use built-in rspec mocks, we use mocha library.

**Question:** would rspec clean out all mocks/stubs created by mocha after each example?

Comment: It looks like the answer is "it would": http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/master/RSpec/Core/MockingAdapters/Mocha:teardown_mocks_for_rspec

Answer (score 0):

One possible point of failure is not telling Rspec that you want to use mocha for mocks:

```
# Where you do your Rspec config stuff
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_framework = :mocha
end
```

AFAIK, for the cleaning up you mention to happen, you need to do that.

[Source](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/mock-framework-integration/mock-with-mocha)

Comment: I use latest rspec and I specify my mock_framework using "config.mock_with :mocha"